# Vector component changes after parallel transport on a curved surface in terms of Riemann Curvature Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In *Einstein's Theory, A Rigorous Introduction for the Mathematically Untrained*:

> The change of the covariant components a vector by parallel transport around an indefinitely small closed curve enclosing a surface with area
>
> $$dS^{\alpha\beta}$$ may now be written
>
> (Equation 9.30)
> $${\Delta}A_{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}R^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha\beta}A_{\nu}\Delta{S}^{\alpha\beta}$$

Here,

$$R^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha\beta}$$

is the Riemann Curvature Tensor, defined as:

> (Equation 9.29)
> $$R^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha\beta}=\Gamma^{\tau}_{\mu\beta}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\tau\alpha}-\Gamma^{\tau}_{\mu\alpha}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\tau\beta}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\beta,\alpha}-\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha,\beta}$$

But Equation 9.28 says

> $${\Delta}A_{\mu}=\left(\Gamma^{\tau}_{\mu\beta}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\tau\alpha}-\Gamma^{\tau}_{\mu\alpha}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\tau\beta}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\beta,\alpha}-\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha,\beta}\right)A_{\nu}\Delta{S}^{\alpha\beta}$$

So where did the factor of one half come from?